# Javascript object becomes undefined when appended to another object

Tags: javascript, object, promise, fetch, undefined

I'm trying to fetch some json data, make it into a Javascript object, then assign it to be a child ENFP of the object personalityData.
In the code below, I use the function `getData` to fetch the json, then assign it to `personalityData.ENFP`. When I log `response` from the second-to-last-line, `response` has type object and the values expected. But when I log `personalityData.ENFP`, it has type undefined and undefined value. I can't figure why this change is happening, since `response` is immediately assigned to `personalityData.ENFP`. Also, `typeof(personalityData)` always returns object.

```
var personalityData = {}
var getData = async function () {
            const res = await fetch("url")
            if (res.status == 500) {
                return '500 Error';
            } else if (!res.ok) {
                return 'response is not ok';
            }
            const jsonData = await res.json();
            return jsonData;
    }
getData().then(response => personalityData.ENFP = response); 
     //console.log(typeof(response)) returns object
     //console.log(typeof(personalityData.ENFP)) returns undefined
    //console.log(typeof(personalityData)) returns object
```

Comment: Where exactly do you put thoes `console.log`s when you comment them in, inside the callback function? `response` is not (should not be) in scope outside of it.

Comment: "*`response` is immediately assigned to `personalityData.ENFP.`*" - no it's not, it's assigned inside a `.then()` callback which runs **later** not immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getData`, which is `async`, and trying to `console.log` the data it is loading immediately in the line below, without waiting for the response.

Step by step, this is what's happening in your code:

1. `getData` is called.
2. `fetch` makes a `GET` request (but the response might take a while to arrive).
3. All 3 console logs are executed (no response has been received yet).
4. Eventually, a response for the `GET` request from above is received.
5. The code after the `await` runs.
6. The `.then()` callback is executed and the response data is assigned to `personalityData.ENFP`, but the `console.log()`s won't run again.

Try moving the `console.logs` inside the `.then()` callback:

```js
const personalityData = {}

function fakeFetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        status: 200,
        ok: true,
        json: () => ({ foo: 'bar' }),
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function getData() {
  const res = await fakeFetch("url");
 
  if (res.status == 500) return '500 Error';
  if (!res.ok) return 'response is not ok';
  
  const jsonData = await res.json();
  
  return jsonData;
}

getData().then((response) => {
  personalityData.ENFP = response;
  
  console.log(personalityData.ENFP);
});
```

Alternatively, you can replace this last `.then()` with `async-await` too:

```js
const personalityData = {}

function fakeFetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        status: 200,
        ok: true,
        json: () => ({ foo: 'bar' }),
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function getData() {
  const res = await fakeFetch("url");
 
  if (res.status == 500) return '500 Error';
  if (!res.ok) return 'response is not ok';
  
  const jsonData = await res.json();
  
  return jsonData;
}

async function loadPersonalityData() {
  const data = await getData();
  
  personalityData.ENFP = data;
  
  console.log(personalityData.ENFP);
}

loadPersonalityData();
```